# How can I define "inline struct" in a class without the need to declare it first in swift (and more)?

Tags: swift, struct

I want to have something like this in my class:

```
class ExampleViewController : UIViewController {

    var dataSource: Struct {
        var customerList: [Customer]? { didSet { reloadDisplay(); } }
        var supplierList: [Supplier]? { didSet { reloadDisplay(); } }
        var inventoryList: [Inventory]? { didSet { reloadDisplay(); } }
    }

    func reloadDisplay() {
        // do UI related things here
    }

}
```

Is this possible, especially to call the parent class' function within the struct? Or if not, is there any workaround this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
class ExampleViewController: UIViewController {

typealias MyDataSource = (customerList: [Customer]?, supplierList: [Supplier]?, inventoryList: [Inventory]?)

var dataSource: MyDataSource? {
    didSet {
        reloadDisplay()
    }
}

func reloadDisplay() {
    // do UI related things here
    print("reload")
}
```

}

Both of the following statements will cause the reload to be triggered:

```
exampleVC.dataSource = (customerList: [Customer](), supplierList: [Supplier](), inventoryList: [Inventory]())
exampleVC.dataSource?.customerList = []()
```

Another alternative is the following:

```
struct DataSource {
    var customerList: [Customer]?
    var supplierList: [Supplier]?
    var inventoryList: [Inventory]?

    init(customerList: [Customer]? = nil, supplierList: [Supplier]? = nil, inventoryList: [Inventory]? = nil) {}
}

class ExampleViewController : UIViewController {

    var dataSource: DataSource? {
        didSet {
            reloadDisplay()
        }
    }

    func reloadDisplay() {
        // do UI related things here
    }

}
```

Comment: Oooooh! Okay! I thought I have to set the whole variable to trigger the didSet. Thanks!!!